# How to shield or cover floodlight for christmas

Tags: lighting

I just bought one of these flood lights from amazon:

[https://www.amazon.com/gp/product/B00OJOMMYK/ref=oh_aui_detailpage_o05_s00?ie=UTF8&psc=1](http://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/B00OJOMMYK)

The flood light is staked to the ground to light up a joy sign I have (this can be seen also here: [https://www.amazon.com/Teak-Isle-Christmas-Nativity-Yard/dp/B00CFNFD5M/ref=sr_1_1?s=lawn-garden&ie=UTF8&qid=1482256657&sr=1-1-spons&keywords=joy+christmas+sign&psc=1](http://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/B00CFNFD5M)).  It does a good job of lighting the sign up but...

I also don't want the extra light hitting the house as I have a few of those laser lights that light up the house.  Is there a top cover or shield to eliminate the extra light from this flood light?

In addition, what can I do to stop the extra light hitting the house and only focus it mainly on the sign.  Can I build or use something to stop this?  Please note I am in Michigan with extremely cold and snowy weather so I cannot use anything to cover the top.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You need barn doors.   Those are the funny black "cards" found on all four sides of theater lighting.

You dont need an actual product; feel free to improvise them any way you can, say with plywood or old election signs.  If they are straight vertical, and thin, they won't accumulate much snow.

[image]

Comment: Yes this is exactly what I mean...God they are hideous...I have some old plywood sitting around..Ill have to think about using that...

Comment: Believe it or not i used some extra pavers to build a tunnel around it. It worked.

Answer (score 3):

I bought 6" drain tile from Menards, cut them to 12" pieces and then cut the bottoms at a 45 degree angle. I put them over my stake light (LEDs) on the grass and it drastically decreased the amount of ambient light around the base - and focused it at the trees. Seems to work so far....

[image: before/after]

[image: 6inch_drain_tile]

Comment: Great job on this I like what you did and its a cheap hack.

Comment: They could even be spray painted green (or brown, I suppose) to match the grass or white to match the snow to reduce their visibility during daylight hours.